# I retrieve a JSONArray with JSONArrays in it instead of JSONObject using the Salesforce Mobile SDK

Tags: mobile, mobilesdk, sfdcmobilesdk-android, smartstore, smartquery

I'm using the SalesforceMobileSDK and I'm having trouble querying my smartstore soup in my native android application. 
When I query my soup I recieve a JSONArray with JSONArrays in it, while it has to be filled with JSONObjects. I think this is because I'm using the "buildSmartQuerySpec" function from the QuerySpec class.

Is it normal that the "buildSmartQuerySpec" returns a JSONArray with JSONArrays in it, which normally should be a JSONArray with JSONObjects?

This is my function to retrieve a JSONArray filled with the smartstore soup:

```
public JSONArray fetchOfflineLeads(){
   JSONArray result = null;
   if(smartStore.hasSoup(LEADS_SOUP)){

      result = query("SELECT {Lead:Name}, {Lead:Company} FROM {Lead}");
      System.out.println(result);

  }else{
      System.out.println("there is no soup");
      return null;
  }
  return result;
}
```

This is my query function :

```
public JSONArray query(String smartSql){
    JSONArray result = null;

    QuerySpec querySpec = QuerySpec.buildSmartQuerySpec(smartSql, 10);
    int count = smartStore.countQuery(querySpec);

    querySpec = QuerySpec.buildSmartQuerySpec(smartSql, count);

    try{
        result = smartStore.query(querySpec, 0);
    }catch(JSONException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "Error when trying to run query");
    }
        return result;
    }
```

I get this when I print my JSONArray out:

```
[["Bertha Boxer","Farmers Coop. of Florida"],["Phyllis Cotton","Abbott Insurance"],["Jeff Glimpse","Jackson Controls"]]
```

While it has to be like this:

```
[{"Name":"Bertha Boxer","Company":"Farmers Coop. of Florida"},{"Name":"Phyllis Cotton","Company""Abbott Insurance"},{"Name":"Jeff Glimpse","Company""Jackson Controls"}]
```

Someone knows what I'm doing wrong? 
Is my string with my smartSql not right?

Comment: Is this related to Salesforce? There may be a better forum for this question.

Comment: Looks to be using the SF mobile SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the syntax table [in the Mobile SDK docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/offline_smart_sql.htm), try changing your smartSql to:

```
result = query("SELECT {Lead:_soup} FROM {Lead}");
```

Note that this should return the entire JSON Lead object, and not an object with only specific fields.  I don't believe you can return arbitrary JSON objects containing only certain field from the originally stored object(s).